# No >256MiB RAM DIMM for Dell Latitude CPx?

Tags: memory, dell-latitude

IIRC, the Dell Latitude CPx takes 144 pin SO DIMMs PC100, yes?

If so, I can't seem to find any memory greater than a mere 256M?  Are these not made in greater capacity, is there another module I can use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way RAM is addressed in the PC100 standard, the MB only support certain memory configurations. In your case it has to be 32Mb (or less) in 64 banks (or less), up to two modules; which is 265MB per slot, and 512 using two of those.